# What is the xsd editor that can make it look simple like this

Tags: xml, xsd, uml, diagram

What is the xsd editor that can make it look simple like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks more like some sort of UML CASE tool with (most probably) support for presenting XSD as class diagram. Some tools enable generating XSD or even whole webservices WSDL from diagram. I've been using this function in Enterprise Architect.

Answer (score 1):

The [Liquid XML Editor](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-editor) allows you to edit an XML Schema graphically, it prevents a logical representation of the XSD making it much simpler to work with.

[image: Liquid XML Studio Oval_Definitions]

It is a commercial product, and in the interests of transparency I should point out I am affiliated with it.